# Does `> div` have a higher importance than anything else in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a container, `single-post-container` and to each `div` inside of it, I assing a padding and a margin, which should be modified by any rules that come after it. On line 2700, I have:

```
.single-post-container > div {
    padding: 0 0 48px 0;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
}
```

But then, on line 2900 (which should override it), I have:

```
.no-related-posts {
    padding: 48px;
}
```

Nothing happens. The `no-related-posts` class simply gets behind the `> div` rule and it's not applied, even if, within the CSS document, it's ahead of it.

```css
.single-post-container > div {
    padding: 0 0 48px 0;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.no-related-posts {
    padding: 48px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="single-post-container">
    <div class="post-content">
        Hello, just testing.
    </div>
    <div class="no-related-posts">
        Related Posts.
    </div>
</div>
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White That's legitimately all the code there is to this issue.

Comment: i dont know how these classes are applied in your html - that would help.

Comment: you should post your HTML to clearify the question

Comment: tag + class more specific than class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be the solution, try it:

```
.single-post-container > div.no-related-posts {
    padding: 48px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm and I can see why.